# Lodash Dictionary replacement in ES6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash, typescript-typings

We've been using lodash in an old TypeScript project. Now we're migrating to ES6 modules so replacing lodash with lodash-es. In lodash there is a `Dictionary` type declared here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/common.d.ts#L247-L249

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}
```

We used it to declare some fields like this:

```
labTransGrouped: Dictionary<Array<ILabtransItem>>;
```

There is no obvious replacement in lodash-es. I assume I should use something like TypeScript Map instead. But what is the right way to use it in type declaration in my case? I could not find any mention of that in lodash changelog or migration guides, so must be something simple.

Comment: Or you can just define your own `Dictionary` interface?

Comment: Did you install @types/lodash-es?

Comment: @Terry yes indeed but that's such a basic concept that I cannot imagine there is no standard way to achieve that. So I just don't want to invent a bicycle.

Comment: @Anatoly yes I did, replaced @types/lodash with @types/lodash-es. Then TypeScript started complaining about Dictionary usages.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem.

`lodash-es` certainly does not have `Dictionary` type, but `Dictionary` is such a simple type you don't even need to create by yourself.

Simply copy the Dictionary type somewhere in your code and import.

```
export interface Dictionary<T> {
  [index: string]: T;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`lodash-es` uses definitions from `lodash` and also `Dictionary`.

```js
import _ from 'lodash-es';
import { Dictionary } from 'lodash';

interface ILabtransItem {
    a: string;
}

const arr: Dictionary<Array<ILabtransItem>> = {}
const groupedArr = _.groupBy(arr, x => x[0].a)
```

Try it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=47#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfTgMyhEcDkAbCATAQwGcALAWgFMjMBuAWAChRJY4BvOAEWAGMZgIAOwJQAnnAC%20KNBhz5iJWo0bBBMClGQEeFOAEkAMgQBGMKAUFE96jG0ZwHcAgC44RM6oDm9BhOUMeIXcnKChXbj4BYTEAHgBBUIJRGMMTMwsrGwA%20LLgAXnY-AKD4TzQAVzAKPASofMQAOjKISoAhUQAKESgAGjgAD3zc-oBtAAYAXQaCAEogA)
See the definition of `groupBy` for `lodash-es` [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash-es/groupBy.d.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Lodash's `Dictionary<T>` fits into a standard Typescript `Record<string, T>` so you can use that if you do not want to define an equivalent type:

```js
const result: Record<string, MyThing> = groupBy(...);
```